# Doing concatenation using concat operation in String or + operator

Tags: java, string

I know about the immutability of String, but I'm confused about how that relates to concatenation.  What will be the output and why for the below piece of code:

```
String str1="my string";
System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str1.concat(" gets appended")); 
System.out.println(str1+" getting updated");
```

Cause, as per my understanding `str1` should not get changed due to its immutability nature. Thus, for all case output should be my string.

Thanks all for all your clarifications. But, please look into the below piece of code and its output,

**Code:**

```
    String str1= new String("First string");
    String str2= "Second string";

    System.out.println("String1: "+str1);
    System.out.println("String2: "+str2);

    str1 = str1.concat(" is now appended");             
    System.out.println(str1);

    str2 = str2.concat(" is now appended");             
    System.out.println(str2);

    str1 = str1+" is getting added";
    System.out.println(str1);

    str2 = str2+" is getting added";
    System.out.println(str2);
```

**Output:**

```
    String1: First string
    String2: Second string
    First string is now appended
    Second string is now appended
    First string is now appended is getting added
    Second string is now appended is getting added
```

Can anyone tell me why it is getting modified? I know to make a string to be modified we need to use StringBuilder class or StringBuffer class. But, here without using those classes it is getting modified even I have used String. 
Is it internally using StringBuilder class or StringBuffer class? I am using jdk version 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will be the output - What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Just a side note, the most efficient way to handle string concatenation in Java is to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.  All the examples you showed are potentially bad performance wise.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are strings, `x.concat(y)` and `x+y` do the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not really. The + operator already uses StringBuilder internally to the best it can, and concat() actually does even better as long as you only need to do one concatenation. StringBuilder is useful when you need to concatenate to a String repeatedly with a loop. In that case the compiler cannot implement + operator with StringBuilders efficiently, so the programmer needs to do so. In other cases, same difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got your explanation. Now I have updated my question, can you please take a look once again?

Answer (score 3):

At *no* point are you changing the reference value of `str1`.  In your example, you're creating two *new* `String` instances which have the value of `str1` and whatever else you're appending there.

Comment: @Makato I have updated my question. Can you please take a look once again?

Comment: @Mani:  You've changed your question.  Before, you weren't doing any assignments or changing reference points.  Now, you *are*.

Answer (score 3):

New `String`  will be returned when calling `str1.concat(" gets appended")` and `str1 + "getting updated"`, it does not affect the original `str1`.

```
System.out.println(str1); // my string
System.out.println(str1.concat(" gets appended")); // my string gets appended
System.out.println(str1 + " getting updated"); // my string getting updated
System.out.println(str1); // my string
```

---

update:

You need to understance the difference between **variable** and **object**.
`str1` is a **variable**, it refers to the string object **First string**. When you call `str1 = str1+" is getting added";`, you are actually let **variable** `str1` refer the new string **First string is now appended is getting added**.

Try this:

```
String string = "original string";
String string_holder = string;
string = string + " contact";
System.out.println(string); // original string contact
System.out.println(string_holder); // original string, the original string is not affected
```

Comment: I suggest adding a fourth line of again printing `str1` which will show that it still has the value `"my string"`

Comment: @Lino I just added it at the same time :)

Comment: @Sun Thank you for your explanation. I have tried new piece of code as you have explained but it seems it is not immutable. Can you please take a look in my updated question?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(str1.concat(" gets appended")); 
System.out.println(str1+" getting updated");
```

The original String is not changed, both create a new String which is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your String does not change when you call str.concat1(str2) is because of how the method is written in the String class. Suppose we make our own little example class:

```
public class MutStr {
    private String str;
    public MutStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public String addString(String input) {
        str = str + input;             //changes the object itself
        return str;                    //returns the changed object
    }
}
```

This class is not immutable, because as the method addString() is run, we change the object itself. However, when we change the method we can make the object immutable:

```
    public String addString(String input) {
        String output = str + input;   //create a new object
        return output;                 //returns the new object
    }
```

Both methods return the same thing; the new String added to the old String, but internally, the first method changes the object itself, while the second method does not.

The key realisation is that the thing that is returned by a method (the thing that is used by the println command) is not the same thing as the object itself.